# Using Get-Variable to retrieve variables from library in Azure Pipelines

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a `HelloWorld` variable library in Azure DevOps containing the variable `$foo=bar`.

I want to read it in my pipeline using `Get-Variable` but regardless of the scope I give to my search, the variable is nowhere to be found. It is however, accessible "directly" (as shown below):

```yaml
variables:
  - group: HelloWorld

stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
    - job:
      displayName: Retrieve variables
      steps:
        - task: Powershell@2
          displayName: Variable retrieval
          inputs:
            targetType: inline
            verbose: true
            script: |
              # This works
              Write-Host "Direct access: $(foo)"
              # All of the following returns nothing
              $indirectAccess = Get-Variable -Name "foo" -ValueOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
              $indirectAccess = Get-Variable -Name "foo" -ValueOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Scope Global
              $indirectAccess = Get-Variable -Name "foo" -ValueOnly -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Scope Script
              Write-Host "Indirect access: $indirectAccess"
```

Can I in any way retrieve library variables with `Get-Variable`?

The reason it's so important for me to know whether it's possible is because I need to retrieve values with variables which name is a variable itself... And so far I haven't found a way to do it except than with `Get-Variable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `$(foo)` is Azure's macro expansion syntax, meaning that the *value* of the variable is injected into the script, so the script doesn't know the name of the variable whose value was used.
- From what I understand, Azure also defines variables as *environment* variables, with the original name transformed to all-uppercase, with `.` replaced with `_`, if applicable. Thus, try accessing the variable as:

  - `$env:FOO` (direct access)
  - `$name = 'FOO'; Get-Content env:$name` (indirect access)

Note that [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) only works for *regular* (PowerShell-only) variables, not for *environment* variables; the latter must be accessed via the `env:` *drive*, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end I used Get-Content with indirect access. Does that mean it's not feasible at all with Get-Variable?

Comment: @avazula, `Get-Variable` only works with regular PowerShell variables. _Environment_ variables must be accessed via the `env:` drive, as shown (`(Get-Item  env:FOO).Value` would work too).